# Почему вызов значения по свойству объекта возрвщает undefined?

Tags: javascript, объекты, key, value

```js
    const obj = {
    '20' : 'content',
    };
    
    let number = '25';
    let key = number[0] + '0'; //key = '20';
    return obj[number[key]]; //undefined
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что вот тут `let key = number[0] + '0'; //key = 20;` в key запишется 20?

Comment: @Grundy а разве нет? number[0] - это цифра 2, потом получается мы добавляем 0 в конец строки и у нас получается key = '20'.

Comment: если `number` - это число, то `number[0]` - это не цифра 2. Собственно ты можешь проверить, что именно записалось в `key`, выведя полученное значение в консоль

Comment: @Grundy виноват, не правильно выноску сделал из основного кода. number = '25'.

Comment: Поправь, в примере в вопросе

Comment: С учетом правки вопроса, теперь непонятно, в чем, собственно, заключается вопрос?

Comment: @Yaant, в том, о чем написано в ответе

Comment: @Grundy Так ведь ответ теперь не соответствует коду в вопросе, а значит, отвечает на какой-то другой вопрос. :)

Comment: @Yaant, ну вообще-то основная часть ответа как раз соответствует :)

Comment: @Grundy ну ладно :) но все равно проголосовал за закрытие вопроса, как вызванного опечаткой :)

Answer (score 1):

надо в начале `number` переделать в строку, и потом брать элемент.

`number.toString()`

и место `obj[number[key]]` пишите `obj[key]`

Comment: Ой, точно, спасибо. Смешная ошибка. Я получается 20-ый символ строки искал в объекте, а не цифру 20.